# MacOS 10.13.3 rsync and terminal: filenames with scandic letters

Tags: macos, backup, rsync

I have a `rsync` backup script that copies my personal files to an external drive with `rsync`:

```
rsync -vr —-delete --progress /Users/omistaja/Documents/ /Volumes/MacExternal/Backups.Omistaja/
```

Edit: It seems that rsync can´t handle scandic letters ö,ä and å. A file that has scandics in it, gets rsynced even though it would allready exists in the destination.

Example: "examplefileöäå.txt" would get rsynced every time even if it exists in the source and destination.

Also the rsync --verbose output in the terminal does not show the letters correctly (see attached image) The letter "ö" gets converted into ?#210

**The filesystems are:**

Source - 
APFS Volume • APFS (Encrypted)

Destination:
CoreStorage Logical Volume - Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)

[image: Scandic ö gets replaced with ?#210]

How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Its not clear what specifically you as asking. I'd suggested an edit to clarify this.

Comment: What format are the two volumes? I.e. are they APFS, Mac OS Extended (aka HFS+), FAT, ExFat, or what?